# Why do I get an ambiguous type variable error using GHC.Generics?

Tags: generics, haskell, ghc

I' ve tried the example from 
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC.Generics#A_generic_function

that is:

```
import GHC.Generics

{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignaturesGeneric #-}

data Bin = O | I deriving Show

data UserTree a = Node a (UserTree a) (UserTree a) | Leaf deriving Generic

class GSerialize f where
    gput :: f a -> [Bin]

instance GSerialize U1 where
    gput U1 = []

instance (GSerialize a, GSerialize b) => GSerialize (a :*: b) where
    gput (x :*: y) = gput x ++ gput y

instance (GSerialize a, GSerialize b) => GSerialize (a :+: b) where
    gput (L1 x) = O : gput x
    gput (R1 x) = I : gput x

instance (GSerialize a) => GSerialize (M1 i c a) where
    gput (M1 x) = gput x

instance (Serialize a) => GSerialize (K1 i a) where
    gput (K1 x) = put x
```

---

```
class Serialize a where
    put :: a -> [Bin]
    default put :: (Generic a, GSerialize (Rep a)) => a -> [Bin]
    put = gput . from

instance Serialize Int
instance Serialize Char
instance Serialize Bool
instance (Serialize a) => Serialize (UserTree a)

toserialize :: (Serialize (UserTree a) ) => UserTree a -> [Bin]
toserialize tree = put tree
```

---

I tested the function with the call:

```
toserialize Leaf
```

here the compiler gives an error-message:

```
 Ambiguous type variable `a0' in the constraint:
   (Serialize a0) arising from a use of `toserialize'
 Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
 In the expression: serialize Leaf
 In an equation for `it': it = toserialize Leaf
```

What is missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that since the type variable `a` in `UserTree a` doesn't appear at all in the `Leaf` constructor, GHC cannot determine which `a` you want for your value. You can fix this by adding an explicit type signature such as

```
toserialize (Leaf :: UserTree Int)
```

UPDATE: The example `toserialize (Node 2 Leaf Leaf)` hangs because the generic representation for `Int` is recursive

```
type Rep Int = D1 D_Int (C1 C_Int (S1 NoSelector (Rec0 Int)))
```

For "primitive" types which don't have "normal" constructors, you usually have to define instances by hand. However, since for example `Bool` is simply

```
data Bool = True | False
```

This works with the generic `Serialize` instance

```
toserialize (Node True Leaf Leaf)
```

Comment: Thank your very much. But now I have a never ending loop inside if I call the function with: _'toSerialize (Node 2 Leaf Leaf)'_ , I think it is because of: **'instance (Serialize a) => GSerialize (K1 i a) where gput (K1 x) = put x'**

Comment: Oh, yes I see the recusive definition in the Generics.hs file for Chars, Ints, Floats...                                                          I hope its not a stupid question, but what instances do I have to define by myself      I tried something like that:       **instance Serialize Int where put = []**  ghc gives then the message:    _Couldn't match expected type `Int -> [Bin]' with actual type `[a0]'
 In the expression: []
 In an equation for `put': put = []
 In the instance declaration for `Serialize Int'_ ** ** And a new instance: **instance Generic Int** is not allowed...